# Static code blocks

Tags: c#, .net, static

Going from `Java` to `C#` I have the following question:
In java I could do the following:

```
public class Application {
    static int attribute;
    static {
        attribute = 5;
    }
   // ... rest of code
}
```

I know I can initialize this from the constructor but this does not fit my needs (I want to initialize and call some utility functions without create the object). 
Does C# support this? If yes, how can I get this done?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 146, accepted):

```
public class Application
{     

    static int attribute;     
    static Application()
    {         
         attribute = 5;     
    }    // removed
}
```

You can use the C# equivalent [static constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors). Please don't confuse it with a regular constructor. A regular constructor doesn't have a `static` modifier in front of it.

I am assuming your `//... rest of the code` need to be also run once. If you don't have such code you can just simply do this.

```
 public class Application
 {     

    static int attribute = 5;
 }
```

Comment: @parapura  this will create an instance of the Application object, I want to run the static block without creating the object

Comment: @GETah It won't... Notice the `static`

Comment: @parapurarajkumar when will the statement 'attribute=5;' statement get executed?

Comment: @RandomUser: Static code (either in a static constructor or in the default value of static members) is run just before the first time the class is accessed (such as by creating an instance object or accessing/calling a static member). If you never use the class, its static code will never run; if you don't use the class until half way through the program, the static code will run at that time.

Comment: @CBHacking `static` is, as far as I know, invoked right after the assembly is loaded. Even if the class is never accessed.

Comment: @GETah That would imply executing every static constructor in the entire core assembly (and any others that are linked to), regardless of whether they'll ever be used. From the link in the answer: "A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced. A static constructor will run before an instance constructor. Note that a type's static constructor is called when a static method assigned to an event or a delegate is invoked and not when it is assigned."

Answer (score 12):

You just can write a static constructor block like this,

```
static Application(){
 attribute=5;
}
```

This is what I could think of.

Comment: this will create an instance of the Application object, I want to run the static block without creating the object

Comment: @GETah: It won't since static keyword is used.

Comment: "A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced."   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc(v=vs.80).aspx    check this page

Answer (score 3):

In your particular scenario, you could do the following:

```
public class Application { 
    static int attribute = 5;
   // ... rest of code 
}
```

*UPDATE:*

It sounds like you want to call a static method.  You can do that as follows:

```
public static class Application {
    static int attribute = 5;

    public static int UtilityMethod(int x) {
        return x + attribute;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I find something else useful. If your variable needs more than one expressions/statements to initialize, use this!

```
static A a = new Func<A>(() => {
   // do it here
   return new A();
})();
```

This approach is not limited on classes.

Answer (score 2):

-A static constructor doesn't have any parameter.
-A static class can contain only one static constructor.
-A static constructor executes first when we run the program.

**Example:**

```
namespace InterviewPreparation  
{  
    public static class Program  
    {  //static Class
        static Program()  
        { //Static constructor
            Console.WriteLine("This is static consturctor.");  
        }  
        public static void Main()  
        { //static main method
            Console.WriteLine("This is main function.");  
            Console.ReadKey();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

**Output:**
This is static constructor.
This is main function.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.